# error: restricted type does not conform to restricting type

Tags: onflow-cadence

My goal is to deploy a custom smart contract that imports core contracts (e.g. FungibleToken) to the Flow emulator. In the flow playground, it works with no errors so the expected result in the emulator is no error. The actual result however is an unhelpful error message about restricted type not conform:

```
execution error code 1101: [Error Code: 1101] cadence runtime error Execution failed:
error: restricted type does not conform to restricting type: FungibleToken.Receiver
```

My smart contract looks like this:

```swift
// ExampleToken.cdc
import FungibleToken from "./FungibleToken.cdc"
```

My flow CLI config looks like this:

```json
{
    "contracts": {
        "FungibleToken": {
            "source": "./cadence/contracts/FungibleToken.cdc",
            "aliases": {
                "emulator": "ee82856bf20e2aa6",
            }
        },
        "ExampleToken": "./cadence/contracts/ExampleToken.cdc"
    },
    "deployments": {
        "emulator": {
            "emulator-account": [
                "FungibleToken"
                "ExampleToken"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The background of this error is that you are trying to deploy your own core contract, while you should only import the core smart contract from their respective addresses.

Remove the deployment of the core contract from your flow CLI config like so:

```json
    "deployments": {
        "emulator": {
            "emulator-account": [
                "ExampleToken"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that there is an issue to make this error message better: https://github.com/onflow/cadence/issues/1169